# In Arrow, traverse consumes a sequence instead of threading the computation

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, sequence, traversal

I'm using kotlin `1.3.41` and arrow `0.10.0-SNAPSHOT`. I want to read all the lines in a file as a sequence:

```
import arrow.core.extensions.sequence.traverse.traverse
import arrow.fx.IO
import arrow.fx.extensions.io.monad.monad
import arrow.fx.extensions.io.monadDefer.monadDefer
import arrow.fx.fix
import java.io.File

val path = "/path/to/file"

fun main() {    
    val b = File(path).inputStream()
        .bufferedReader()
        .lineSequence()
        .traverse(IO.monad()) {
            IO.monadDefer().later { it }
        }
        .fix()

    b.unsafeRunAsync {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I  get the following exception :
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This sequence can be consumed only once.`

If I'm not using `traverse`, then I don't get the exception.
The documentation says: `Sequences can be iterated multiple times, however some sequence implementations might constrain themselves to be iterated only once.` This makes sense for a buffered reader. I guess that means that the sequence is iterated by `traverse` at least twice. I've tried to look at `traverse` source code but I wasn't able to fully understand it.

I don't understand why traversing the sequence should consume it. Can't I just thread the computation?
Is there any way to do a `traverse` like operation without consuming the sequence?